# Terminal issue with virtualenvwrapper after Mavericks Upgrade

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenvwrapper, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to OSX Mavericks, I am getting this message in the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Comment: Are you sure that virtualenvwrapper.sh is supposed to be in /usr/bin/python or have you installed it into a different version of Python (e.g. installed with Homebrew?)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try reinstalling pip and then reinstalling virtualenvwrapper (I had to go through these steps after upgrading to Mavericks):

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: Yup, I reinstalled pip and upgraded with the [python scripts](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html), then used your advice to upgrade virtualenvwrapper. All is well now, much thanks.

Comment: this worked for me, but only after re-installing easy_install as per [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac)

Answer (score 11):

Re-arrange the export order so that the `python` path is placed before the `virtualenv` commands in your `.bash_profile` file.

```
# python path
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# needed for virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: And don't source virtualenvwrapper.sh from .bashrc - that is called early in .bash_profile.

Answer (score 6):

Try edit .bash_profile file

```
# Home brew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# virtualenvwrapper 
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: The only one that worked for me on macOS High Sierra. Thanks @Tuan

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend running pip with sudo. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19755902/544059) was my solution for the same problem (after upgrading to Mavericks).

In essence, uninstall any virtualenv and brewed Python you had before (use `which <command>` to check that you removed everything except the system Python in `/usr/bin/python`) and cleanly install them once again:

```
brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
# Open a new terminal tab now (to access /usr/local/bin/python)
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper` will fix the issue but never used `sudo pip` this will change system-wide. If pip throws permission errors without `sudo` then you should fix those and then try only with `pip install <--upgrade> $(package)`.

I rather suggest install `homebrew` and then install `pip` using `brew install pip` which will install latest stable version of pip for you.

1. Install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then run `brew doctor` . If there are any warnings fix those(actually brew will tell you how to fixed those).
2. You may need to remove system-wide python comes with Mac and use `brew` to install required versions. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774529/what-is-the-safest-way-to-removing-python-framework-files-that-are-located-in-di) to remove system-wide python
3. Use `brew install python` or/and `brew install python3` to install required python version/s.
4. Finaly run `pip install --upgrade  virtualenvwrapper`
5. Now on never use `sudo pip` only use `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with MacOS High Sierra. I was able to fix it with these lines in my .bash_profile file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Code
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: What is `Code`?

Comment: @chrisFrisina Code is a directory inside my /home, you can change it and name as you want to, after creating the directory

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure the path properly. Run the following commands in the terminal:

1. `which python`

Output -

```
/usr/bin/python
```

2. `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Output -

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

3. `echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`

   /usr/local/bin/python

So as you can see that the variable `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` is pointing towards the wrong python path. So we need to reset the path of variable `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`.

4. `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`

now run the following the command:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: I have the same problem but in the step 3 when I run **echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON** I get **usr/bin/python3 <br/> Because in the step 1 I have **usr/bin/python**

Comment: Step-3 here was super helpful for me because all along I was pointing to the wrong `python` path. Once I got that path right, it cleared the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Running these two commands helped me get rid of it (had done a software update on macOS High Sierra)

```
$ sudo easy_install pip

$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Cross-verify PATH in .bashrc with following commands:

```
which virtualenv
which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

output of:

```
echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
```

and

```
which python3
```

should be same
which is

> /usr/bin/python3

Configure the path accordingly to above results

> export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
>
> export MY_PROJECT=~/my_proj
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD=1
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
>
> export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV='result of which virtualenv'
>
> source 'result of which virtualenvwrapper.sh'

if after verifying path still INITIALIZATION HOOK ERROR REMAINS.

Then, In `source` left everthing as it is just replace `virtualenvwrapper.sh` with `virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`

Then it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).