# Error: Environment /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/iron does not contain activation script

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am running python 3.7.6 on macOS Catalina version 10.15.1 and I am trying to install and set up `virtualenvwrapper` which I have installed with `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`.

I have the following lines in my .bash_profile:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Users/maxcarey/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenv
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs 
source /Users/maxcarey/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

These are configuration steps I have followed from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643313/5420796. As well as other tutorials ([like this one](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/))

So you can see I'm attemping to point these export variables to the right place, in my terminal, the output of `which python3` is `/usr/local/bin/python3`
The output of `which virtualenv` is: /Users/maxcarey/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenv.
The output of `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` is `/Users/maxcarey/Library/Python/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Here is the problem: when I run: `mkvirtualenv iron`  to create a new virtual environment (called iron in this case), the output of the command is:

created virtual environment in 193ms CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/maxcarey/.virtualenvs/iron, clear=False, global=False) with seeder FromAppData pip=latest setuptools=latest wheel=latest app_data_dir=/Users/maxcarey/Library/Application Support/virtualenv/seed-v1 via=copy
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/maxcarey/.virtualenvs/iron/bin/predeactivate
ERROR: Environment '/Users/maxcarey/.virtualenvs/iron' does not contain an activate script.

You can see that a virtual environment is indeed created, however, I get an error saying there is no activation script. However, when I navigate to `~/.virtualenvs`, I can indeed see the activation scripts. Here is the output of `tree` inside the new folder `iron/local/`:

```
└── local
    └── bin
        ├── activate
        ├── activate.csh
        ├── activate.fish
        ├── activate.ps1
        ├── activate.xsh
        ├── activate_this.py
        ├── easy_install
        ├── easy_install-3.7
        ├── easy_install3
        ├── pip
        ├── pip-3.7
        ├── pip3
        ├── python -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
        ├── python3 -> python
        ├── python3.7 -> python
        ├── wheel
        ├── wheel-3.7
        └── wheel3
```

It does indeed appear that there are activation scripts. So I am stumped about why I get the activation script error (which I also get when running `workon iron`). I have tried simply destroying and recreating the virtual environment with `rmvirtualenv iron`, which works, however, when creating the environment again I still get the same error. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to add `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=usr/local/bin` to my shell startup file *after* the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script gets called.

I figured out this fix after looking at the source and seeing that it was creating the `activate` script in `usr/local/bin`, but the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script was looking in just `bin` for some reason.

My full shell startup config is now this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm running on a raspbian buster with Python 3.7.3. I ran into the same issue, "ERROR...no activation script". I tried @Lombax answer but it didn't work.

However, I noticed that the version of `virtualenvwrapper` I had installed was 5.0.0. I checked on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper/#history) and it's still at version 4.8.4. So I uninstalled virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper: `sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`.

Then I reinstalled both and specified the version: `sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper=='4.8.4'`
I sourced my .bashrc, in which I had appended the settings:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And now `mkvirtualenv test` works.  Not sure what's the bug with version 5.x of virtualenvwrapper, in the meantime, this got around the problem for me, hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @simon. Thanks for your response. In my case, I am getting the same activation script error after downgrading. One thing to note is that I am not using `sudo` to install these packages because then I run into another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216679/usr-bin-python3-error-while-finding-spec-for-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader/33239250

Comment: this worked for me with opencv 4.2.0 and raspberry pi 4

Comment: worked for me with opencv 3.3 downgraded virtualenvwrapper to 4.8.4

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error message when I used `mkvirtualenv` on a new RPI4. I added these lines to my `.bashrc` and it fixed the problem for me:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=bin  # <== This line fixed it for me
```

This is a variation of the answer from @maxmcmahon, above, but setting VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR to "bin". I did not need to change the versions of either virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper; the current versions installed by default were fine.

Comment: This worked but i'm not sure that I understand why...thank you.

Comment: @Rob, when I got the error, I went to the GitHub and looked at the virtualenvwrapper source code(https://github.com/bernardobarreto/virtualenvwrapper/blob/master/virtualenvwrapper.sh). I found the error I was getting in the source code and then searched for where my activation script had been placed. I found where the activate script actually was. I then set VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN=bin in order to point to it. It had to be a relative reference because the virtualenvwrapper.sh script used it inside a directory specification and a leading / caused 2 //'s in a row which lead to the error.

Comment: In my case the bins were located at `local/bin` instead, so setting `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=local/bin` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The error show because the virtual environment which created is not activated.
Don't panic, you just need to activate it by running a particular command.
For me after doing `$mkvirtualenv cv -p python3`, the virtual env has created, but not been activated.
After the above command you type `source /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/activate`, it will activate the virtual environment variable.
It worked for me.
Now my command line looks like:

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you run the `mkvirtualenv <your venv name>` command and failed.

What you want to do is locating the activate script in your `WORKON_HOME` path (aka the path to `.virtualenv` folder). Here go to your new venv folder  and find the activate script.

For example, mine is in `.virtualenv/<my venv name>/local/bin`. Here you would add to your `.bashrc` file: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I was just hitting this, downgrading my virtualenv version to 20.0.3 allowed me to get around the issue.

`pip3 uninstall virtualenv && pip3 install 'virtualenv==20.0.3'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after following your steps still getting exact same issue described above :(

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment on maxmcmahon's answer above.
The solution seems to NOT be backwards compatible with python3.9.
I tested this with homebrew on macOS.
Possibly depending on your platform according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig._get_preferred_schemes
which seems to build scripts under usr/local/bin instead of bin as of python 3.10.
So one might have to shift the VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR variable on and off. I noticed that setting it only in the current shell I could run

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3 devel3.10
```

without issues, but when not set I could no longer active devel3.10.

```
workon devel3.10
ERROR: Environment '~/.virtualenvs/devel3.10' does not contain an activate script.
```

And when set I can't create another python3.9 venv. It fails with the same error message.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32454588)

Comment: You are right that it's not an answer and I'm sorry, it was never meant to be an answer. I don't have reputation to comment and I found no other way to report my findings.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me. Python3.7 to Python3.8 is generating a venv containing a bin directory. But Python3.11 is generating with a local/bin directory.

To fix it I have to run the creation for python3.11 like this:

VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=local/bin mkvirtualenv -p python3.11 my-app

And when creating for other pythons:

VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=bin mkvirtualenv -p python3.7 my-app

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
pip install --force-reinstall virtualenvwrapper
. ~/.bashrc
```

fixed the issue.

Greetings,
Peter